# Console Says Internal Server Errror?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

My Console Browser Says Internal Server Error but my connection and path on file is already ok what should i do ??

Ill try to json decode my array form database in sql column but still cant find my target data

```
//GET PATIENT LIST TABLE
function get_bereavement_risk_list_table(){
    $arr = array();
    $g = 'SELECT bvpoc_mrno,bvpoc_no,bvpoc_dateassesed,bvpoc_entered,bvpoc_risklevel,bvpoc_formdata,bvpoc_lastupdate,
    patient_mrno,patient_lastname,patient_middlename,patient_firstname
    FROM bereavement_poc a LEFT JOIN tblpatients b ON a.bvpoc_mrno = b.patient_mrno';
    $r = $this->connect()->prepare($g);
    $r->execute();
    if($r->rowCount()>0){
        while($rr = $r->fetch()){
           $riskarr = json_decode($rr['bvpoc_formdata']);
           $risklname = $riskarr[0];
           $riskfname = $riskarr[1];


           $risk['lname']  = $risklname;
           $risk['fname'] = $riskfname;

           array_push($arr,$risk);
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}
```

POST https://bdhospice.com/pages/reports/bereavement_letter/bereavement_risk_report/bereavement_risk.class.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: do some basic debugging first please. What is the error message? (Check your error log.) Are you sure it refers to the function you've posted here? I'm not going to spend ages staring at this function when I have no idea if there is even a problem with it or not - and nor will anyone else here. If you give the error message we've all got a fighting chance. (Also I'm not sure why you've tagged this with javascript and ajax, it seems like a purely PHP problem to me.)

Answer (score -1):

By going to the link you provided, browser catches the 404 error, not the 500.
By the way, try using a different browser or cleaning your browsers cache, cookies (associated with the site you're getting the error on).
500 error is server-side error, meaning the problem probably isn't with your connection but instead with the website's server, maybe it crashed or something, try refreshing it.